# How long can I store crushed and whole grain?

Tags: storage, malt, grain

I want to buy a large pack (25kg) but i will only use 10kg to start. How long can I store the rest? How long can they be stored if crushed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what type of malt but assuming you are looking at base malts this should be accurate, It's directly from Briess's website referring to 2 row pale malt. Darker roasted malts will differ somewhat.

STORAGE AND SHELF LIFE 
Store in a temperate, low humidity, pest free environment at 
temperatures of <90 ºF. Improperly stored malts are prone 
to loss of freshness and flavor. Whole kernel diastatic and 
preground malts are best when used within 6 months from 
date of manufacture. Whole kernel roasted malts may begin 
experiencing a slight flavor loss after 18 months.

http://www.brewingwithbriess.com/Assets/PDFs/Briess_PISB_2RowBrewersMalt.pdf